# Apache crashes on Symfony2's @ParamConverter

Tags: php, apache, symfony, xampp

I tried porting a Symfony 2.3 project to another computer so that I could continue working on the project. The computer had PHP 5.5.6, and upon entering a certain route, I would get a "Connection reset" error.

I did some research and apparently, 5.5.6 had issues that forced it to crash. Moreover, Windows' Event Viewer said that Apache had crashed several times. So, I upgraded PHP to 5.6.20. It was no good, so I tried to isolate the code that would cause the crash by commenting the view and the code until nothing but the bare bones would remain - and it still crashes.

If I enter regular routes with no ParamConverters my application works just fine. But I double checked with another route that uses a ParamConverter and it crashes in a similar way.

This is the Event Visor's output in XML format.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
        <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
        <Level>2</Level> 
        <Task>100</Task> 
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-07T01:41:14.000000000Z" /> 
        <EventRecordID>119233</EventRecordID> 
        <Channel>Application</Channel> 
        <Computer>localhost</Computer> 
        <Security /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>httpd.exe</Data> 
        <Data>2.4.7.0</Data> 
        <Data>528e59ed</Data> 
        <Data>php5ts.dll</Data> 
        <Data>5.6.20.0</Data> 
        <Data>56fda37a</Data> 
        <Data>c00000fd</Data> 
        <Data>0011e0e2</Data> 
        <Data>2be4</Data> 
        <Data>01d1906e8dc1781a</Data> 
        <Data>C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe</Data> 
        <Data>C:\xampp\php56\php5ts.dll</Data> 
        <Data>d0053828-fc61-11e5-bb8a-e81132695005</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

This event is thrown immediately after I try to access this route. And my controller method contains nothing but a call to a template that calls nothing on the model, and a @ParamConverter that makes a certain query depending on the input.

For the record I am using Windows 7 Home Basic.

What could be the cause of this crash? Thank you.

EDIT: I am also using XAMPP 3.2.1. I did not upgrade XAMPP, only the PHP version and modified the corresponding file before testing that PHP would be working with the new version properly by calling `phpinfo()`.

EDIT 2: Tried with a newer, fresh XAMPP installation and it fails exactly at that same point.

EDIT 3: This is specifically an Apache error. I decided to use nginx as my web server and this issue does not exist at all. Is this a bug?